# How to configure WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS in YAML file for Jackson deserialization in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I receive a timestamp as a number from a javascript application and my `RestController` exposes an endpoint with a bean structure and a `ZonedDateTime` to store this value.

There is a check into the `InstantDeserializer` class for the WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS DeserializationFeature, and the value is always true even if I put the following configuration in my application.yml:

```yaml
spring:
    jackson:
        deserialization:
            WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS: false
```

Any ideas?

---

My YAML configuration is not read. Even if I put all the features to false, I still get the context.isEnabled(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS) test to true in InstantDeserializer :

```
spring:
    jackson:
        serialization:
            WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS: false
            READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS: false
        deserialization:
            WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS: false
            READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS: false
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that reads the configuration from `application.yml`? Thanks!

Comment: there is no code, I expect that Spring do that

Comment: there is something wrong in our application and librairies we wrote, because when I start a simple web app with a simple controller endpoint with PostMapping and a bean with a ZonedDateTime attribute the following configuration works perfectly spring:
    jackson:
        deserialization:
            READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS: false

Comment: any ideas on what goes wrong or any clues to search ?

Comment: You would need to add some code then ;)

Comment: I will have a look tomorrow but our code / configuration is too complex ;-)

Comment: sorry, but we wrote dozens of spring boot starters and it's too hard to extract a minimal code

Comment: Maybe that is the issue, having dozens of spring boot starters ;)

Answer (score 1):

That is a `SerializationFeature` not a `DeserializationFeature` one, so try the following:

```yaml
spring:
    jackson:
        serialization:
            write-date-timestamps-as-nanoseconds: false
```

Check the [reference documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS).

(*Thanks @Arnaud for the hint*) Given that you seem to be interested in deserialization it might instead be relevant to check the following feature:

```yaml
spring:
    jackson:
        deserialization:
            read-date-timestamps-as-nanoseconds: false
```

You can also configure it using a Configuration file:

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);
    }
}
```

Check the [reference documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS).